# Initial Value of an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a class with a property which is an enum

The enum is

```
/// <summary>
/// All available delivery actions
/// </summary>
public enum EnumDeliveryAction
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Tasks with email delivery action will be emailed
    /// </summary>
    Email,

    /// <summary>
    /// Tasks with SharePoint delivery action 
   /// </summary>
   SharePoint
  }
```

When I create an instance of this class, NOWHERE in the code, do I specify the value of the enum field, but it seems to default to the first item in the enumlist, and not a null value, is this how enums work? How is it possible to ensure that the enum gets some kind of null value if it is not set, I don't want it defaulting to the first value in the enum.

Comment: Enum is a value type, as opposed to a reference type.  Reference types will be defaulted to null, whereas, value types will be defaulted to a value.  I.e. int defaults to 0, date time's default to the minimum date, etc.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Default value for `enum` types is `0` (which is by default, the first element in the enumeration). Fields of a class will be initialized to the default value.

If you need to represent an *unknown* value in the enum, you can add an element `Unknown` with value 0. Alternatively, you could declare the field as `Nullable<MyEnum>` (`MyEnum?`).

Comment: So do I need to start my enums first value with 1?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Not unless you want the default value to be undefined.. .It will still default to a value of zero, which, if your enum does not have a member with value zero, will be an illegal value..

Comment: Charles: not *illegal*. In C# (unlike Java), it's considered legal to have enum values outside the defined range.

Comment: +1 You can keep your enum the same if you make it nullable by defining it as MyEnum?, or add a default value, in this case, "None", to indicate a "null" condition. I tend to prefer the second, since I think excessive use of nullable variables starts to look messy.

Comment: It's a logical illegality. But that's beside the point. Back on track, FxCop will complain if you don't have an element in your `enum` with the name None. Presumably this is your default 0 value. Good habit to get into.

Comment: @LeakyCode, IMHO, `NotSet` instead of `Unknown` is a better choice.

Comment: For reference: [CA1008: Enums should have zero value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

Enums are a value type, like ints.  You need to make it nullable so as not to default to the first (or 0-defined) enum member.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public EnumDeliveryAction? DeliveryAction { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: or add an undefined member:
public enum EnumDeliveryAction  {Undefined=0, Email=1, Sharepoint=2 }

Comment: Polaris: `Nullable<T>` is identical to `T?`.

Comment: Yes.  T? is identical to Nullable<T>.

Answer (score 9):

Enum fields are initialized as zero; an if you don't specify values in an enum, they start at zero (`Email = 0`, `SharePoint=1`, etc).

Thus by default any field you do initialize yourself will be `Email`. It is relatively common to add `None=0` for such cases, or alternatively use `Nullable<T>`; i.e.

```
/// <summary>
/// All available delivery actions
/// </summary>
public enum EnumDeliveryAction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Not specified
    /// </summary>
    None,

    /// <summary>
    /// Tasks with email delivery action will be emailed
    /// </summary>
    Email,

    /// <summary>
    /// Tasks with SharePoint delivery action 
   /// </summary>
   SharePoint
}
```

You should also be sure to never treat your last *expected* value as a default; i.e.

```
switch(action) {
    case EnumDeliveryAction.Email; RunEmail(); break;
    default: RunSharePoint(); break;
}
```

this should be:

```
switch(action) {
    case EnumDeliveryAction.Email; RunEmail(); break;
    case EnumDeliveryAction.SharePoint; RunSharePoint(); break;
    default: throw new InvalidOperationException(
          "Unexpected action: " + action);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Best practice (as advised by Code Analysis) is to always have a default value in your enums, which represent an unset value.

So in your case, you might have:

```
public enum EnumDeliveryAction
   {

    /// <summary>
    /// Default value
    /// </summary>
    NotSet,

    /// <summary>
    /// Tasks with email delivery action will be emailed
    /// </summary>
    Email,

    /// <summary>
    /// Tasks with SharePoint delivery action 
   /// </summary>
   SharePoint
  }
```

As an aside, you shouldn't prefix the name of the enum with Enum. You might consider changing to:

```
public enum DeliveryAction;
```

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree with adding an "Undefined" enum member in .Net since that's what null means by definition - unknown.  Seems redundant to redefine null in every enum you create.

Comment: Seems to me that having a default value in your enum is a much better practice than using nullable enums.

Comment: @JoshKodroff Well, you can either deal with the problem in two separate blocks using `null`, or in one `switch` or function lookup table by using an `unset` enum value. I prefer one block ot LUT, with the error condition handled inline with the rest. it's cleaner and more self-descriptive that way.

Answer (score 6):

Enums are value types.  Value types cannot be null and are initialized to 0.

Even if your enum does not have a 0, enum variables will be initialized to 0.

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2
}
```

(later)

```
SomeEnum x = default(SomeEnum);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Outputs - 0

---

Some answerers are advocating using `Nullable<T>` to match your initialization expectations.  Becareful with this advice since `Nullable<T>` is still a value type and has different semantics than reference types.  For example, it will never generate a null reference exception (it's not a reference).

```
SomeEnum? x = default(SomeEnum?);

if (x == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's null!");
}
if (x > SomeEnum.B)
{
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This runs even though you don't expect it to");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start your enums at any value (such as 1), but when they represent a lookup value in a Database, you generally want them to match up.

I generally declare the first Enum as None ( = 0) when it makes sense to do so, as per the .Net Framework Design guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional aproach to adding a null to values that don't generally have one is to declare your variable as a nullable type, ie:

```
EnumDeliveryAction? action=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a value of None = 0 as your first enum value. Make it explicit, then you know for sure what it's value is.

Answer (score 0):

By default only reference types are nullable types. If you want a variable to allow nulls you have to define it as nullable using the "?" character (for this you need C# 2.0 or up).

```
enum MyEnum
{
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo
}
```

and in your class

```
MyEnum? myvariable = null;
```

Comment: I think you mean that only *reference types* are nullable by default, as both reference and value types are considered objects in .NET

Answer (score 0):

My C++ teacher in college (11 years ago) told me that the linker replaces enum with their actual type:

`typedef   static const int   enum;`

Thus, any time you write something like `enum MY_VAL = 5;`, you could easily replace with `static const int MY_VAL = 5;` (but that just makes your code longer...).

Anyway, the default value of any `int` is 0.