# Enums and no field with value '0'

Tags: c#, enums

I've made the following test code:

```
public enum Test
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
public class User
{
    public Test Flag { get; set; }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
var user = new User();
var value = typeof(Test).GetField(user.Flag.ToString());
```

Value will be `null` since it seems like `User.Flag` is initialized with `0`. Why is that? `0` is not a valid value for my enum. Shouldn't it be initialized with the first valid value (`1`)?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1165414/25727

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question on Initial Value of an Enum (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165402/question-on-initial-value-of-an-enum-c)

Comment: @Jan: Thanks. Didn't see that one. Closing my own question as a dup

Comment: Not quite the duplicate, as the other question does not define values on the enum (so the first item _would_ have a value of `0`). The answers to that one do apply though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums are backed by integral types and behave like them (mostly).

Unfortunately, that means that you can assign *any* value that is valid on the underlying type to an enum - there is no checking.

In the case of default initialization, that would be the default value of the underlying type, which for integral types is `0`.

You can do this as well and it will compile and run:

```
var value = (Test)43;
```

Perhaps re-define your enum as the following:

```
public enum Test
{
    None = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

The [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) class has some handy methods to work with enums - such as [`IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) to find out if a variable holds a defined value of the enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

It's initialised with the default of the underlying type, which is `int` and `default(int)` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Underlying type of the Enum is `int` type by default, and default value obviously is `0` (you can specify custom underlying type but only primitive numeric like `enum CustomEnum : byte`)

**1.10 Enums, C# Specification:**

> Each enum type has a corresponding integral type called the underlying
>   type of the enum type. An enum type that does not explicitly declare
>   an underlying type has an underlying type of int. An enum type’s
>   storage format and range of possible values are determined by its
>   underlying type. The set of values that an enum type can take on is
>   not limited by its enum members. In particular, any value of the
>   underlying type of an enum can be cast to the enum type and is a
>   distinct valid value of that enum type.

Answer (score -1):

`GetField` takes the name of the **property name**, and you are passing the enum value of `user.Flag`

You should write

```
var value = (Test) typeof(Test).GetField("Flag").GetValue(user);
```

Comment: The other three answers should have given you a hint ;)

Comment: Actually, I didn't see any answer when I opened and found out later. I am so sorry about this. Hope you understand