# Putting array into Enum

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

this might be a stupid question, but is it possible to put array into Enum?

```
public enum Owners { Me, Neutral, Enemy[] }
```

My problem is, that I don't know the number of enemies before hand, so I would love to use it like `Owners.Enemy[3]`. Is it this possible to do with Enum or should I just create a separate class for owners?

Comment: It sounds like you should create a separate enum for enemy types.

Comment: enum members must be known at compile time. If what you are doing involves stuff unknown at compile time, you can't directly map it to an enum.

Comment: It's not clear what `Owners.Enemy[3]` would even mean. I think you need to reconsider your design.

Comment: As already answered: Impossible. It's also pointless. Why ? Enums are created so that a human programmer can read "Me", "Neutral", "Enemy" and instantly know what it stands for. Whatever you're trying to do defies the logic of enum structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an extension method for Owners enum like such:

```
static Enemy[] Enemies;
static Enemy getEnemy(this Owners owner,int index){
return Enemies[index];
}
```

Comment: Check the following link for extending enums: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388072/how-to-add-extension-methods-to-enums

Answer (score 0):

Enum might not be the right fit for what you are trying. It is a compile time representation for different values, helping you to replace magic numbers in your code by meaningful names.

Not knowing much about your application, I reckon you are probabably better off defining an object for each individual

```
var me = new Thingy();
var neutral = new Thingy();
var enemy1 = new Thingy();
var enemy2 = new Thingy();
```

And assigning the proper object to the field as you see fit, e.g.

```
class Something
{
    public Thingy Owner { get; set; }
}
```