# How can we extend all enum type?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, extension-methods, generic-programming

**How can we extend all enum type?**

I want to extend all enum type with a new method called "ToStringConstant". This method will return the integer value as String. Here is what I have so far, but compilator won't allow enum in the where clause.

```
    public static string ToStringConstant<T>(this T EnumVar) where T : enum
    {
        return ((int)EnumVar).ToString();
    }
```

Example :

```
public enum Example
{
    Example = 0
}

void Method()
{
    Example var =  Example.Example;
    var.ToString();//Return "Example"
    var.ToStringConstant();//Return "0"   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add extension methods to Enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388072/how-to-add-extension-methods-to-enums)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the method generic, just accept an `Enum`:

```
public static string ToStringConstant(this Enum EnumVar)
{
    return ((int)EnumVar).ToString();
}
```

On a side note, casting to `long` instead of `int` will ensure that the code functions regardless of the underlying type of the enumeration.

Comment: Note that this can fail for enum types which don't have `int` as their underlying types. (It's a problem in the OP's code, but just something to be aware of.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, it'll work fine for enums with byte/short or any other smaller integer types.  It'll break on `long` unless you cast to `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: For some weird reason, compilator say "Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'".

I will use Convert.ToDouble instead...

Comment: @AXMIM You should use `Convert.ToInt64` as it is an integer value, not a floating point value.