# Why is this switch statement not exhaustive?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I have this enum

```
    public enum ActionStatus
    {
        WINDUP, ACTIVE, COOLDOWN, DONE
    }
```

and this property

```
    public int TicksUntilNextStatus => Status switch
    {
        ActionStatus.WINDUP => WindupEnd - CurrentTime,
        ActionStatus.ACTIVE => ActiveEnd - CurrentTime,
        ActionStatus.COOLDOWN => CooldownEnd - CurrentTime,
        ActionStatus.DONE => 0
    };
```

`Status` is declared as `public ActionStatus Status { get => ... }`

the compiler issues a warning that the switch is not exhaustive. Why?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098644/switch-statement-without-default-when-dealing-with-enumerations) and its responses may inspire you. Look at the second response in particular.

Comment: Another thing to consider from the above link, what if you're not the owner of `ActionStatus`, and one day `ActionStatus` adds a new value `NOTACTIVE`. A default case needs to be added to circumvent this scenario, which can be done using the _ operator.